# What's the music playing in Naruto Shippuden episode 1 when Naruto and Jiraiya are walking through the forest?

Tags: naruto, music

There's a music playing in *Naruto Shippuden* episode 1 when Naruto and Jiraiya are walking through the forest back to the Hidden Leaf village.

I have listened to all the *Naruto Shippuden Original Soundtracks 1-3* but have not found it. I also could not find an episode list listing the music in each episode on the web.

What's the music title?

Answer (score 1):

There are a large number of soundtracks in *Naruto* that were never released officially. For these songs, sometimes you can find an unofficial version online. Fans construct these versions by splicing together audio samples from various episodes, so if there aren't enough samples, the audio can be partially distorted due to voice removal manipulations and the like.

For this particular track, it seems that there was a particularly good sample from *Shippuden* episode 343, so no splicing needed! It's been uploaded to YouTube titled as ["Peaceful Theme"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1O04qZv3-4) and also ["Konoha Peace"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kY4j_2HGPHg).